# A simple message board with WYSIWYP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am making a simple message board with some WYSIWYP function using cakePhp 1.26.
I have googled for some hints and finally reached this URL:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/tags/view/wysiwyg

But I am not sure which one is the best out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use TinyMCE personally, http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Just remember to set your content escaping properly, or use the Sanitize component, http://book.cakephp.org/view/153/Data-Sanitization

Comment: Have a look at the CakePHP TinyMCE Plugin developed by CakeDC: http://cakedc.com/eng/downloads/view/tinymce